# Cover a cicular hole with planks

Tags: recreational-mathematics, discrete-geometry, tiling

A friend of mine asked me the following question.

> Whats the minimum number of rectangular planks of unit
>   width (and infinite length) needed to cover a circular hole with diameter $n$?

Obviously, $n$ is an upper bound because the hole can be covered by putting $n$ planks in parallel next to each other. Also it is easy to see that for small $n$, in particular $n=2$ and $n=3$ one cannot make do with fewer than $n$.

Is there a proof that in the general case $n$ planks are needed?

Comment: Maybe I'm not unerstanding, but I think the answer is just $n$. How can you add $1$ less times than $n$ and get something $\geq n$?

Comment: My intuition tells me that the question becomes a little less straightforward when the diameter is not an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a theorem of Bang from 1950-51, solving Tarski's Plank Problem. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski's_plank_problem)  for description and links.

Answer (score 4):

Extend the circulare hole to a sphere and extend each plank vertically (both up and down). With each of the planks associate the surface area of that sphere it covers. Since the surface area of a spherical cap is proportional to its height, we conclude that each plank covers at most $\frac1n$ of the sphere surface. Since they jointly shall cover the whole sphere, we need at least $n$ planks.

Comment: It appears that this was Tarski's proof. The paper by Bang, mentioned in my answer, solves a problem that includes the circle as a special case.

Answer (score -1):

How many pieces of unit width planks and infinite length are needed to cover a hole of diameter n?

Easy!

One piece :)

Just cut up each bit as required from that infinite length piece :)

Comment: Your construction is unclear.